Finding the global minimum of a convex-like optimization problem
Given an optimization problem of the following form:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \quad & f(x)\\
\textrm{s.t.} \quad & g_i(x) \leq 0 \\
& h_j(x) = 0
\end{aligned}
$$
with $f$ pseudoconvex, $g_i$ quasiconvex and $h_j$ quasimonotonic.
Since the lower level sets of quasiconvex functions the level sets of quasimonotonic functions are convex, we know that the constraints form a convex set $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$.
Additionally, it is known that for a pseudoconvex function $f$ a local minimum is always a global minimum.
Finally, I don't know if this is helpful for my question but for completion sakes, it is proven that if a feasible point exists fulfilling the KKT conditions for the above problem this point is the global minimum.
My question now is if I insert this problem into a NLP solver and get a local minimum, must this local minimum be always the global minimum. Or does the transformation destroy this property and introduce additional minima?
I couldn't find anything regarding this. I only know that for a standard convex problem we always get the local=global minimum. But is this true for this kind of optimization problem?

I would be very surprised if you could get anything beyond local minima in this general case without using (intractable) global optimization techniques.
The class of quasiconvex functions are not closed under summation, even summing a quasiconvex function with a linear function might not be quasiconvex as shown in this post. So the Lagrangian function of your problem can have many local minimal and so the KKT conditions can have many solutions corresponding to them.
